# Redirect to a default page, if any get request page takes too long to reply

Tags: node.js, express

I was wondering if I can redirect any request coming to server to a default page, if my server for some reason has not been able to respond.

For example, for this **route**:

```
app.post('/login',ensureAuthenticated,(req,res)=>{
    // My route logic
});
```

some unexpected error occurred (database unable to connect), I could send them to the my home page.

Comment: I don't get?! You want `redirect` when it's take to long time to response or when an error came up?!

Comment: yes. but not for one particular request, but every request

Comment: For error you should use try-catch or callbacks, and for timeout I think a middle will do

Comment: a middle will do? try-catch is what I have tried. However for some cases, try catch doesn't work.(say, when its taking too long). I was wondering if I can count time from when I get any request and redirect to home page if say, it takes more than 10 sec. app.get(' * '){//some logic to wait for 10 sec and redirect}. However the problem is I would be sending two response. one from app.get('*') and other from the original intended response

Comment: Did you try `setTimeout(() => { // do the redirect }, 10000)` before the `// logic`?!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/login',ensureAuthenticated,(req,res)=>{
    // My route logic
    setTimeout(() => {
      res.redirect('/default-page')
    }, 2000)
});
```

Using the `setTimeout` function, if the API didn't respond in 2 seconds `res.redirect` with execute and redirect your page to a default url.

Comment: The thing is above method wont work for all the cases(say too many redirected page). I want something that is not dependent on any particular get request but all request in general

Comment: if I am not wrong, you want to apply this logic to many posts or get requests? For that, you can add it to a middleware.